# Fixing non-portable files in R package

Tags: r, package

I am updating one of my R packages. The new version includes a Shiny app within an `\inst` folder as detailed here:

https://deanattali.com/2015/04/21/r-package-shiny-app/

Here is what is returned by `devtools::check_built()`:

```
> checking for portable file names ... WARNING
Found the following files with non-portable file names:
inst/shiny/HACSim-RShiny-App-master/www/Phillips et al. (2020).pdf
inst/shiny/HACSim-RShiny-App-master/www/Sphyrna lewini_aligned.fas
```

These are not fully portable file names.
See section ‘Package structure’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.

I looked in the relevant section of the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual, but am still scratching my head.

Is there a workaround here that I'm missing?

Comment: The "1.1 Package structure" section says *"we exclude space as many utilities do not accept spaces in file paths"* as well as *"It would be good practice to avoid the shell metacharacters `(){}'[]$~`"*, both of which are a factor for you. Is it a problem to rename the files so that they contain neither spaces nor parens?

Comment: Said differently, the goal of "maximum portability" is likely borne from experience and problems on various platforms. One cannot really work around this, as violating that premise will risk making the package misbehave on some platforms where those filenames will be a problem. Since the problem with those filenames has nothing to do with R, I think you're stuck with it. Options, as I see it: rename the files; combine them into a `.zip` or `.tar` file so that they are still included in the package albeit less-convenient; provide a link if indirect access is acceptable.

Comment: Ah ok. I will try those suggestions.

Comment: The problem was solved by using underscores in place of spaces and parentheses.